# Laravel excel export row and column issue with dynamic column and row

Tags: laravel

```
public function collection()
{
    return FeedbackSubmission::select('student_id','feedback_id','question_id','answer','inputType','email','created_at')->where('feedback_id', $this->id)->get();
}

public function map($row): array
{
    $questions = TempFeedbackQuestion::where('feedback_id', $this->id)
        ->where('type', '!=', 'paragraph')
        ->pluck('question', 'question_id')
        ->toArray();
    $answers = [];
    foreach ($questions as $questionId => $question) {
        $answer = ''; // Initialize the variable inside the loop
        // Check if both the question and answer are present in the row
        if (isset($row['question_id'], $row['answer']) && $row['question_id'] === $questionId) {
            $dbAnswer = $row['answer'];
            if ($row['inputType'] == "checkbox-group") {
                $answer = implode(', ', json_decode($dbAnswer));
            } else {
                $answer = $dbAnswer;
            }
        } 
        $answers[$question] = $answer; // Use question as key instead of index
    }
    $answers['created_at'] = $row['created_at'];
    return $answers;
}

public function headings(): array
{
    $questions = TempFeedbackQuestion::where('feedback_id', $this->id)
        ->where('type', '!=', 'paragraph')
        ->pluck('question')
        ->toArray();
        $questions[] = "Submitted Date";

        return $questions;
}
```

[image]

In excel its creating new row when any question is submitted with empty answer. its working file if all question have answer. What is the issue in map methode please check and suggest me to fix the issue.